# Angular 17 ERR_ABORTED 404 after project initialization

Tags: angular, angular17

i want to create an Angular 17 application, but I can't even run the application after project setup.
I have `node 20.10.0`.
I ran `npm install -g @angular/cli`
Then `ng ng new ProjectName --no-standalone --style=scss --routing=true`
This installs the application.
Then I con into the project folder and start the application with `ng serve` and open localhost:4200.

But then I get a white page and in the console I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ6Av.png)

Am I doing something wrong or do I need additional configuration?

Comment: could you please post `package.json` file and `index.html` or your base `href`?